# SQL Server: Count based on date and two different times

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date, sum

OS - WindowsXP

SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2

I am trying to get a count of the number of projects based on the release date, NOT date and TIME.  However, some projects have the same release date but a different time and are treated as a separate project.  As long as the project has the same date, I want it to be counted.

'Releasedate' on the server is a "datetime"

```
Select ProjectName, count(ProjectName) as Count, (Releasedate)
From DBTable Where Releasedate >= convert(nvarchar,(getdate())) 
Group by   projectname,releasedt
```

Current Results:

```
 ProjectName       Count        Releasedate

 Project_Nm_1      1             2010-03-27 00:00:00
 Project_Nm_1      1             2010-03-27 08:00:00
 Project_Nm_2      1             2010-03-27 00:00:00
 Project_Nm_2      1             2010-03-27 08:00:00
```

I would like to see:

```
 Project_Nm_1      2             2010-03-27
 Project_Nm_2      2             2010-03-27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the date portion of the ReleaseDate datetime using

```
DateAdd(dd, 0, DateDiff(dd, 0, ReleaseDate))
```

Therefore your query becomes

```
SELECT 
    ProjectName,
    Count(ProjectName) as Count,
    DateAdd(dd, 0, DateDiff(dd, 0, ReleaseDate)) as ReleaseDate
FROM
    DBTable
WHERE
    ReleaseDate >= getdate()
GROUP BY
    ProjectName,
    DateAdd(dd, 0, DateDiff(dd, 0, ReleaseDate))
```

If you find yourself stripping the time from datetimes frequently, then encapsulate it in a UDF.

Comment: Thank your for your help with this.  Ian had the answer I was looking for. Daniel, I will look into combining the "DATEPART"s into one date.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 2008 introduced the new **`DATE`** datatype which does exactly what you're looking for - handle only the date, without any time. So just `CAST` your field to `DATE` and you should be fine:

```
SELECT 
   ProjectName, COUNT(ProjectName) as Count, CAST(Releasedate AS DATE)
FROM 
   dbo.DBTable 
WHERE 
   CAST(Releasedate AS DATE) >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
GROUP BY 
   projectname, CAST(ReleaseDate as DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

To group by date only, try using the CONVERT function:

```
GROUP BY projectname, CONVERT(nvarchar, Releasedate, 101)
```

You'll want to use the same `CONVERT` function call in the select column list so that query's output shows just the date, as well.

Take a look at:
http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=56536

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    ProjectName, count(ProjectName) as CountProjects, Releasedate
From 
    DBTable 
Where 
    Releasedate >= convert(nvarchar, getdate()) 
Group by   
    projectname,releasedt
Order by 
    CountProjects desc
```

P.S. Don't use built-in functions while choosing alias of any column

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply `GROUP BY` the parts of the date you want using `DATEPART`

```
SELECT
    ProjectName,
    Count(*),
    DATEPART(year, Releasedate) as ReleaseYear,
    DATEPART(month, Releasedate) as ReleaseMonth,
    DATEPART(day, Releasedate) as ReleaseDay
FROM
    DBTable 
WHERE
    Releasedate >= convert(nvarchar,(getdate()))
GROUP BY
    ProjectName,
    DATEPART(year, Releasedate),
    DATEPART(month, Releasedate),
    DATEPART(day, Releasedate)
```

I'll leave combining those parts into one field as an exercise for you if you want, but this will ignore the time portion of `Releasedate` when grouping

Answer (score 0):

To explain:

```
declare @dt datetime
set @dt = '2010/12/22 12:34:56'
print @dt
print convert(char(8), @dt, 112)
```

Result:

```
Dec 22 2010 12:34PM
20101222
```

So, use

```
GROUP BY convert(char(8), releasedt, 112)
```